# Openstack noVNC (console) is automatically disconnected after a period of time

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, novnc

When I connect to the console of Openstack instances over noVNC, it is automatically disconnected after a period of time without any interactions. Is there any way to disable this feature or increase the timeout?